# Is it an expensive operation to access data stored in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I am wondering if it is an expensive operation to access data (string, bool) stored in `NSUserDefaults`. Is that significantly slower than accessing it once and storing it in a property, then using it in the future by obtaining it from the property as opposed to getting it from `NSUserDefaults` again? Or are the differences quite insignificant? I know the docs state `NSUserDefaults` is cached.

The answer likely depends on how often you plan to fetch it. Let's assume it will be needed 20 times every minute. I won't be changing it programmatically, only fetching the current value.

I'm curious because one benefit of always fetching it is you can guarantee that is the current value. If you get it once and store it you need to listen for changes to `NSUserDefaults` then update the value stored by fetching it.

Comment: Are these things "UserDefaults"? If not they don't belong there, create a Data Model class and save/restore as necessary.

Comment: As for performance, unless you are experiencing performance issues it is not a question worth considering, it is called: Premature Optimization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> At runtime, you use an NSUserDefaults object to read the defaults that
>   your application uses from a user’s defaults database. NSUserDefaults
>   caches the information to avoid having to open the user’s defaults
>   database each time you need a default value. The synchronize method,
>   which is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, keeps the
>   in-memory cache in sync with a user’s defaults database.

Following the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html), while you aren't using the `synchronize` method, fetching values from `NSUserDefault` shouldn't be an expensive operation. So, while you are only fetching a value and not setting it, your operation won't be more expensive than direct access from a property.